# Fast ajax responses in Symfony2

Tags: ajax, performance, symfony, tags

I have a tagging text field that while typing in a new tag, suggests similar existing tags.
The suggestions are retrieved by an ajax request to a controller which pulls them with from the DB with Doctrine. i.e:

- **Request** `/tags/suggestions?q=foo`
- **Response** `["foo","food","fool"]`

The problem is that the request is too slow (atleast 2 seconds, in *prod*) which in this case is too much.

**Is there a way to make the request faster?**
According to the profiler, the main time consumer is *kernel.request* with 50% of the total time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but kernel.request is the event dispatched by the kernel, which is caught and processed. IMHO you should look to benchmark the code you have inside the controller.

Comment: I'm also not sure what the *kernel.request* is but there is also a *controller* in the timeline so I'm not sure it's a controller issue..

Comment: It may depend on your machine too. It may perform faster with a better maschine setup.

Comment: If you are talking of the timeline in the profiler, you are not really in production mode. The profiling takes quite some time itself.

Comment: I used the profiling in dev to see what takes most of the time, but the late response was measured in prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if kernel.request is slow , it's not necessarly a symfony side issue.

you should look to optimize your server by updating your Apache with php-fastPGM instead of php standard module.

you should also activate a cache manager like php  APC which reduce a few more the requests .

for example i run a symfony project on a raspberry pi . Before these tweaks , one request with 8 database request took around 25 seconds to display. After these tweaks, a page was displayed in less than 3 seconds ( an average of 2.5 s )

another list of possible tweaks  :

http://slides.liip.ch/static/2012-05-18_symfony-speed.html#9

Answer (score 0):

You could ask doctrine(if you're not already doing so) to fetch the result as array(without converting your whole query to a bunch of objects) by using:

```
$q = $em->createQueryBuilder('t')->(...);
$q -> getQuery() -> fetchArrayResult();
```

Should speed up things a little.

Comment: The database actions is really not the problem here, even if I return a hard-coded array without Doctrine interaction the response is slow..

Answer (score 0):

For small pages such as *ajax autocomplete* I decided to use [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) which is a micro Symfony2 and it gets me an elegant and fast solution.